add a subdomain to a domain in cpanel for my laravel project
I have a project that i want to be a subdomain from the main domain so that the url will read like this steveprojects.com/realestate/ this will redirect to the home page,steveprojects.com/realestate/upcoming-projects this will read the upcoming projects url. the subdomain here is the steveprojects.com/realestate/ and the main domain is the steveprojects.com/ ..how can i achieve this?
i have created the subdomain folder,"realestate",in the public_html but when i try to access it this way steveprojects.com/realestate/ i get a 404 error that the url isnt available but it exists.i have added the .htaccess file in the public folder.here is my index.php file  in the public folder which is inside the project folder
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../../realestate/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../realestate/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../realestate/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);



make sure your project structure are placed correctly
In your .htaccess put on correct path and also add RewriteBase /realestate/ to handle subdirectory urls
assuming now you have correct path in index.php, you
now should define your routes to point 
/ to your dashboard controller and
/upcoming-project to its upcoming controller

